# Use nativeElement in two components

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am get this error when using autocomplete for angular maps(AGM),

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

, when using `ElementRef` for angular `public searchElement: ElementRef;`.

line am getting the error:

```
  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  public zoom: number;

  @ViewChild("search")
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //set google maps defaults
    this.zoom = 4;
    this.latitude = 39.8282;
    this.longitude = -98.5795;

    //create search FormControl
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    //set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();

    //load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          //get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          //verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          //set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

In my view component

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">
  </div>
  <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

Am using this in two components, in one it works fines on the other it give thats error. Have tried to use different names for element ref but sting the same error.

Comment: Have you considered adding template reference `searchElement` in your template file? Or `search` template reference, if you have the variable declared like `@ViewChild("search") public searchElementRef: ElementRef;`

Comment: @AmitChigadani This is what I have in my template `<input class="uk-input uk-form-width-medium" placeholder="search area" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
                                                    spellcheck="off" type="text" #search>`

Comment: You should declare a variable like  `@ViewChild("search") public searchElementRef: ElementRef;` instead of `public searchElement: ElementRef`, which means `searchElement` variable is referring the `search` template reference mentioned inside your template `(#search)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable like

`@ViewChild("search") public searchElementRef: ElementRef;`

instead of

`public searchElement: ElementRef`

which means `searchElement` variable is referring the `search` template reference mentioned inside your template as `(#search)` w.r.t `input` element.

Comment: Can you please add the entire code of component and template file to your question? or create a http://stackblitz.com link with your problem

Comment: Chigani have made the requested changes.

Comment: Your code works fine. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yotsns I have copied the imports from the link you have provided.

Comment: What is the relation between the second component and the component you are showing here. Can you create a complete http://stackblitz.com with all your code. So that it is more clear.

Comment: on the first component it runs without any issue but the second one it doesn't, the first one is for adding the location while the second one is for editing the location.

Comment: Same code apart from preloading the current location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172999/discussion-between-amit-chigadani-and-gerald-brigen).